# Arabic Saudi Arabia not available in Regional Formats list

Tags: 12.04, language-support, arabic

I installed Arabic support in Ubuntu 12.04 but there is no Arabic Saudi Arabia in Regional Formats list. All other Arabic regional formats are available e.g. Arabic UAE, Arabic Syria, Arabic Kuwait, Arabic Bahrain etc but not Arabic Saudi Arabia !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround solved the problem for me (on both systems):
I removed Arabic support, re-installed it, and Arabic Saudi Arabia has now appeared in Regional Formats list.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Arabic language added to the list of system languages

[image]

[image]

You will have the option to choose Arabic SA from the regional format Tab as seen below

[image]

[image]

Try this:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: As you can get the idea from my question, i have already installed Arabic in language support, because i see all other Arabic formats e.g. Arabic Syria, Arabic UAE, Arabic Bahrain etc. in the Regional Formats but i don't see Arabic Saudi Arabia... I am using Edubuntu 12.04 and a friend of mine is using Ubuntu 12.04, and we both have same problem.

Comment: So that's not what you're looking for?  The regional format image (the last image) shows clearly the Arabic Saudi Arabia Regional Format.

Comment: I can see it in the image you have provided, it means you have it but I don't have any Arabic Saudi Arabia in my Regional Formats list, that's the problem ! that's why i am asking the question, if it was there why i would be asking??

Comment: Can you supply an image of your Language Support window?

Comment: here: http://ubuntuone.com/4AI9cLPwgoEELDUfm7mc2K

Comment: If it works let me know.